# Energy density at a given scale in terms of the Energy Spectrum

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence, scales

#### Background:

Let us have a turbulent fluid with a random velocity field $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x})$.
The **volume averaged kinetic energy density** $\mathscr{E}_K$ can be expressed as

$$\mathscr{E}_K=\frac{1}{2V}\int d^3\mathbf{x}\,\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}).$$

We decompose this velocity field in terms of its Fourier components $\mathbf{\tilde{u}}(\mathbf{k})$ as

$$\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^3\mathbf{k}\,e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\,\mathbf{\tilde{u}}(\mathbf{k}),$$

and define a **spectral energy density** $E_K(k)$ as

$$\frac{{\tilde Q}_{ii}({\bf k}) }{(2\pi)^3}=\frac{E_K(k)}{2\pi k^2},$$

where ${\tilde Q}_{ij}({\bf k})$ is defined as

$$\left<(\tilde{u}_i)^*(\mathbf{k})\tilde{u}_j(\mathbf{k}')\right>=(2\pi)^3\delta^3(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}'){\tilde{Q}}_{ij}(\mathbf{k}),$$

and $\tilde{u}_i(\mathbf{k})$ is the $i$-th component of $\mathbf{\tilde{u}}(\mathbf{k})$.

The volume averaged kinetic energy density $\mathscr{E}_K$ can then be written as

$$\mathscr{E}_K=\int_0^\infty dk\,E_K(k).$$

#### My Question:

I am trying to get a physical intuition for the energy density at a particular scale. Let's say I am interested in a certain wavenumber scale $k_1$. The energy density *per wavenumber* at that scale is $E_K(k_1)$. Is it reasonable to say that the energy density contained at the scale $k_1$ is $k_1E_K(k_1)$? This is dimensionally okay, since it has the same units as $\mathscr{E}_K$, but is it a physically meaningful statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close to the right interpretation but the correct way to view things is to look at energy density contained between $k$ and $k + dk$. This small interval has an energy of

$$ \mathcal{E}_K = E_kdk$$

This statement, is true for every variable-dependent densities. Consider for example the wavefunction in quantum mechanics $\psi(x)$. You ask the probability for the particle to be in $\textbf{some region}$ and not at a point. The probability that it the particle is between $x$ and $x+dx$ is given by

$$ P = |\psi|^2dx$$

Adding this $dx$ or in your case $dk$ allows you to still say

$$ \sum P_i = 1, \hspace{0.5cm} E_{total} = \sum_{k} E_k$$

in the continuous notation.